# Dayname from 3 letter code

Tags: php, date

Currently I'm doing

```
$dayNames = array(
        'Sun'=>'Sunday',
        'Mon'=>'Monday', 
        'Tue'=>'Tuesday', 
        'Wed'=>'Wednesday', 
        'Thu'=>'Thursday', 
        'Fri'=>'Friday', 
        'Sat'=>'Saturday', 
     );

$weekday=$dayNames[$dayCode]; //where $dayCode is Sun, Mon...Sat
```

Is it the good way or there are any native PHP function for that ?

Comment: Where do you need them for? You can get a lot from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$shortDay = 'Sun';
$fullDay = date('l', strtotime($shortDay)); // Sunday
```

Explanation: with `strtotime`, you essentially parse the given short dayname, constructing a new date based on it. With `date('l')` (it's lowercased `L`, not `1`), you format it back into full textual representation of the day of the week.